# Why doesnt my image bind until I save my contentpage unless I save and reload

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I'm currently trying to bind a few properties when I click a button and it pushes a new page.

Starting from the top, this is how my app is setup

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

I have a "MainPage" which is essentially the first page that shows when starting the app.

In my `MainPage.xaml`

I've set the `BindingContext` to the `MainViewModel`

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

And I also have a button which has it's `Command` bound to a Command in my `MainViewModel`

```
<Button Text="New Goal" 
        HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" 
        TextColor="White"
        Margin="10"
        CornerRadius="4"
        Command="{Binding NewGoalCommand}">
    <Button.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#8FDF70" Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#1DBE95" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

The `MainViewModel` is pretty straightforward. It has a `Command` property which I initialize in the constructor

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public Command NewGoalCommand { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    NewGoalCommand = new Command(() => ShowNewGoalPage());
}

private async void ShowNewGoalPage()
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new NewGoal(SelectedItem));
}
```

**NewGoal.xaml**

As you can see in the code it's invoking `NewGoal` which is my second page which shows up when I click the button, this page does show up when I click the button which to me, indicates that the binding was successful.

The same goes for this page, I'm setting the `BindingContext` to my other `ViewModel` which is responsible for it's corresponding view, like so

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModel:NewGoalViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

And I've also added components which are going to bind to it's corresponding property so that when I click "Save" it adds that item to the collection inside the `MainViewModel`

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
        <Image WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
               Margin="10"
               Source="{Binding ItemModel.ImageSource}"/>

        <StackLayout Margin="20,0,20,0"
                     Spacing="0">
            <Label Text="Title"/>
            <Entry />
        </StackLayout>


        <StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,0"
                     Spacing="0">
            <Label Text="Description"/>
            <Entry />
        </StackLayout>


        <StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,0"
                     Spacing="0">
            <Label Text="Type"/>
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding ItemModel.Type}" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,0"
                     Spacing="0">
            <Label Text="Price"/>
            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric"/>
        </StackLayout>


        <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                Text="Save"
                VerticalOptions="End">

        </Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And here is the `NewGoalViewModel`

```
class NewGoalViewModel : MainViewModel
{
    public Item ItemModel { get; set; }
    public Command SaveCommand { get; set; }


    public NewGoalViewModel()
    {
        ItemModel = new Item();
        ItemModel.Title = "Title";
        ItemModel.Description = "Description";
        ItemModel.Type = SavingsType.Other;
        ItemModel.Price = 19.00f;
        ItemModel.ImageSource = "cash.jpg";


        SaveCommand = new Command(() => AddGoal());
    }

    private void AddGoal()
    {
        Items.Add(new Item { Title = "Rainy Day", Type = SavingsType.Other, Price = 100.00, ImageSource = "cash.jpg" });
    }
}
```

**The issue**

So when I start the app and I click the first button, it takes me to the next page.
when I land on that page, it should show me an `Image` at the top. It's bound to a property which I've assigned in the constructor `ItemModel.ImageSource = "cash.jpg";`

The issue is however is that it doesnt actually bind, resulting in the image not showing until I save the `NewGoal.xaml` page and it reloads. Once it's done reloading it shows the image.

Comment: What do you mean by `save the NewGoal.xaml`? I test you code and it works well on my side. Is your ImageSource declared as property?  `public string ImageSource { get; internal set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying

```
    private Item itemModel { get; set; }
    public Item ItemModel 
    {
        get { return itemModel ; }
        set
        {
            itemModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and inherit your ViewModel to  `: INotifyPropertyChanged`
and add this to implement

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: Oh wow.. I just realized that I also set the binding context in the code-behind in the constructor of the NewGoals page by doing `BindingContext = item;` and passing in an object with the name `item` as a parameter. Removing this fixed it. I believe this is because it priorotize that binding context over the xaml one.